# Youtube Data API v3 playlistitems endpoint returning empty items array

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using the `playlistItems` endpoint to get a list of videos that have been uploaded by an account. The response shows `1` as totalResults, which is expected, but the `items` array is empty, which is not. It's not clear to me what's going on, since the video is public and has views on it.

I'm not seeing this issue pulling uploads from other accounts, so I'm wondering if it's a caching issue on the YT side, or some setting we need to enable on our account? I'm not able to find any documentation that would explain what's happening here.

The endpoint I'm hitting is `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=<api key>&playlistId=UUjQYaIbYceXNNdC63dQ9aTg&maxResults=10&part=snippet`, and the full response I'm receiving is:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/eJKYM5x3WquVgzqxNc7NMRuOS4o\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The item is now showing up, so it looks to just take some time before the API reflects what's been uploaded.